# Algorithm for finding approximate area of the ground via elevation grid?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have a 200X200 grid/array (i.e. 40,000 values) of 10mX10m "pixels" whose values indicate the average elevation of the land at that point.

Across the grid there are vast connected regions where the elevation values are 0m because they represent actual sea.

**Question**: is there a quick algorithm for obtaining the approximate area of land? I understand that I may multiply 200^2*10^2 to obtain a rough approximation of the area, but some of the values vary quite a bit.

I think I know a rather expensive way, i.e. by summing all of the triangles whose vertices lie at the elevation. But is there a faster/easier way?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf That is not the case, this isn't a class assignment. I'm a math major, not a CS student. I'm writing programs/scripts for a drone (UAV club), and I've obtained the data I've mentioned via the Google Maps API with another script I wrote. This is part of a (Python) class that returns information about the ground over which the drone is flying.

Comment: I can't tell if the task is to exclude the sea tiles (since sea != "land", and why mention sea otherwise), or to calculate the "3D area" of all tiles, or both.  If you want the 3D area, bear in mind that any approximation could be arbitrarily bad unless you have a bound on the steepness of the ground.

Comment: So are you looking for simply the number of land tiles (level > 0) inside your array, and multiplying that with 10m²? That would approximate the area after projecting it to the ground plane (i.e. ignoring the heights except for determining if it's water or not).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) are the tools for this kind of problem. Here's a synthetic 200×200 landscape with points on a 10 metre grid and height ranging up to 40 metres above sea level:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> xaxis = yaxis = np.arange(0, 2000, 10)
>>> x, y = np.meshgrid(xaxis, yaxis)
>>> z = np.maximum(40 * np.sin(np.hypot(x, y) / 350), 0)
```

We can have a look at this in [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/):

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
>>> _, axes = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
>>> axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=plt.get_cmap('winter'))
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, the number of points on land (that is, with height greater than 0) is trivial to compute, and you can multiply this by the size of a grid square (100 m² in your question) to get an estimate of the land area:

```
>>> (z > 0).sum() * 100
1396500
```

But from the question, I understand that you want a more accurate estimate, one that takes into account the slope of the land. One way to do that is to make a mesh of triangles covering the land, and add up the area of the triangles.

First, turn the coordinate arrays into an array of points (a [point cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_cloud)):

```
>>> points = np.vstack((x, y, z)).reshape(3, -1).T
>>> points
array([[  0.000000e+00,   0.000000e+00,   0.000000e+00],
       [  1.000000e+01,   0.000000e+00,   1.142702e+00],
       [  2.000000e+01,   0.000000e+00,   2.284471e+00],
       ..., 
       [  1.970000e+03,   1.990000e+03,   3.957136e+01],
       [  1.980000e+03,   1.990000e+03,   3.944581e+01],
       [  1.990000e+03,   1.990000e+03,   3.930390e+01]])
```

Second, use [`scipy.spatial.Delaunay`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/spatial.html#delaunay-triangulations) to triangulate in two dimensions, getting a surface mesh:

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
>>> tri = Delaunay(points[:,:2])
>>> len(tri.simplices)
79202
>>> tri.simplices
array([[39698, 39899, 39898],
       [39899, 39698, 39699],
       [39899, 39700, 39900],
       ..., 
       [19236, 19235, 19035],
       [19437, 19236, 19237],
       [19436, 19236, 19437]], dtype=int32)
```

The values for each triangle in the triangulation are the indexes in the `points` array of the three points in the triangle.

Third, select the triangles that have some land in them:

```
>>> land = (points[tri.simplices][...,2] > 0).any(axis=1)
>>> triangles = tri.simplices[land]
>>> len(triangles)
27858
```

Fourth, compute the areas of these triangles:

```
>>> v0, v1, v2 = (points[triangles[:,i]] for i in range(3))
>>> areas = np.linalg.norm(np.cross(v1 - v0, v2 - v0), axis=1) / 2
>>> areas
array([ 50.325028,  50.324343,  50.32315 , ...,  50.308673,  50.313157, 50.313649])
```

Finally, add them up:

```
>>> areas.sum()
1397829.2847141961
```

That's not very different to the original estimate, which is to be expected because the slopes are shallow.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! And for the last computation (i.e. computing the areas) it appears you used the shoelace formula (also in Widder's Advanced Calculus), which is awesome; I found that, but I doubt I would have come up with a way to compute it as efficiently as you have.

Answer (score 1):

First some additional stuff that's useful for testing:

```
# a function to create a random map as simulated input for testing:
def get_map(x_size, y_size, h_min, h_max):
    import random
    return [[random.randint(h_min, h_max) for x in range(x_size)] for y in range(y_size)]

# a function to nicely print the map for debug and visualization
def print_map(hmap):
    print(*hmap, sep="\n")
```

Then we write the actual land area calculator:

```
# calculate approximate land area where the height is greater than zero
# map is a list of lists, tile_size is in m², min_level is the sea level
def calc_land_area(hmap, tile_size=100, min_level=0):
    land_tiles = sum(len([tile for tile in row if tile>min_level]) for row in hmap)
    return tile_size * land_tiles
```

Now a test:

```
hmap = get_map(5, 5, 0, 3)
print_map(hmap)
print("land area:", calc_land_area(hmap), "m²")
```

That could result e.g. in this random example output:

```
[2, 0, 3, 0, 2]
[3, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 1, 3, 0]
land area: 1700 m²
```

You see 8 sea tiles on a map of 25 tiles, so 800m² are sea and 1700m² are land.

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/NEzqSn)

Comment: Instead of `len([tile for tile in row if tile>min_level])`, which creates a list and then throws it away, write `sum(tile > min_level for tile in row)`.

Comment: @GarethRees Right, that looks like an improvement. Thanks!